# How can i read pixels info in SDL2

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

How can i read a pixel's rgb value and how to replace it with other value in SDL2? and can anyone tell me what is the meaning of 'format of the pixel'
 I would appreciate it if someone can explain to me how to obtain R, G, and B values from the pixel and replace it with the new RGB value.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [`SDL_RenderDrawPoint()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawPoint) and [`SDL_RenderReadPixels()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderReadPixels).

But keep in mind that working with separate pixels is usually not advised. There are special functions for drawing lines, images, etc. And they're probably faster than what you would be able to come up with.

---

In simple words, 'Pixel format' describes how many bits a single pixel occupies, and how various colors are incoded into those bits.